# OpenGL - Drawing a square with glDrawArrays()

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I am drawing a square with glDrawArrays() as follows:

```
glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,-6.0f);  
const GLfloat quadVertices[] = { -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 
        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 
        1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f,
        -1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f
    }; 

    glVertexPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, quadVertices);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
```

The output is not as expected.

Comment: GL_QUADS is deprecated since OpenGL 3, has been removed in OpenGL 3.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, quadVertices);
```

as you are only using 3 floats per vertex, not 4.

Comment: Yup, got it. I was mistaking this 3 for the number of vertices. Thanks a lot!